Can turbo trainers be easily damaged when instaling a cassette?
I have now had to return a second direct drive trainer (the same brand, different model, ~600 € price range) after it produced bad sounds and even some roughness when pedalling. They may just have been bad pieces, and the warranty claims were accepted, but I am still worried whether I did something wrong and may do something bad to another model I will buy. I installed the cassette as I would do on a bicycle wheel, using a torque ratchet set to 40 N.m. In the first one I was able to hold the wheel, in the other it was under a fairing so I had to use a chain whip. That means the force acting on the wheel can be substantial if both levers point down. Are the hubs supposed to withstand such force?
After installing the cassette, one just plugs in the thru axle plugs, installs the bike, and secures the thru axle using a torque wrench. There is probably not much that can go wrong.

This is a good question. I also doubt that overtightening the cassette would do this. The recommended torque is 40 Nm, which is a lot of torque for home tools. That said, if someone had overtightened that, this might damage the bearing in the freehub body. Now, I think it's just one bearing that might be affected, and it should bind (that is, not rotate freely, usually felt as notchiness). This would produce noise when the flywheel rotates. I don't know how much noise.
There are going to be a pair of bearings inside the trainer body that support the flywheel axle, because any rotating part needs to pivot on a bearing or a bushing. If the bearing failed early, then possibly the bearing was defective, or the bearing seat was out of tolerance.
NEW: To confirm, users in this situation can place a hand near the axle of your freewheel and rotate it by hand. You may be able to feel the roughness, although you might have to partly disassemble the trainer to get closer to the bearings. If they're gone enough, you should probably hear a screech.
My case happened outside of warranty. If you'd searched on Youtube, you or a skilled mechanic should have been able to figure out which bits to remove to access the bearing. Another item that could wear out, by the way, is the drive belt, but I think that's less likely. The problem with the bearings is that they may not have been designed for easy removal. I lucked out and had a bike mechanic who was able and willing to replace mine, but he said he had to use some tools that weren't standard at bike shops to get the bearing out. I didn't see the exact configuration of the bearing. It might have been that he couldn't get a bearing puller positioned anywhere. They need enough of a small flat surface to push against as they pull the bearing out; you can see what I mean in this YouTube video by another bike mechanic. The extremely non-preferred option is that you can hammer the bearing out, but this can damage the bearing seat, which is also not good. Also, if the bearing seat was out of tolerance, then the new bearing would also prematurely fail.
It sounds like Vladimir's failures occurred close to purchase, which is fortunate. I would guess there's a problem with manufacturing quality. Perhaps its a batch issue, and he was unlucky to get two trainers from the affected batch and was either unlucky to have them both fail or lucky they both failed during the warranty period.

While outside the question scope, it's possible that smart trainer manufacturers did not design their trainers to be serviced. This is less than ideal! They are expensive pieces of equipment, and it can logically be expected that bearings might wear out. If the bearings cannot be serviced, then the entire smart trainer has to go into the trash if one fails.
If they were making all the seats to extremely fine tolerances and speccing ultra-long life bearings, then maybe this is fine. CeramicSpeed has a headset bearing that has the bearings encased in some sort of polymer that contains oil and also really keeps contaminants out. The idea is that because headsets with cables routed through the bearings are very expensive to service, you might as well all but eliminate the need to service them. I somehow doubt that trainer manufacturers made this design decision, but I would welcome any contradictory info.

"tools that weren't standard at bike shops..."  For some reason has me imagining a big unshaven guy in greasy overalls with sledgehammer and coal chisel :)

Impact wrench of some sort, I think.
